# TextView of an activity from SmsListener class

Tags: android, textview

I have SmsListener class for catch SMS and i have TextVew in my main Activity, after receive incoming SMS i need update TextView in main activity

```
    public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();         
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String msg_from;
                if (bundle != null){
                    try{
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                            msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

there i want update TextView on my Main activity
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
    //                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Help me

Comment: i need pass msgbody to textview in another activity

Comment: And there are multiple ways to do so, which one of them have you tried? You need to make an effort before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity initialize a variable of MainActivity class like below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private static MainActivity ins;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ins = this;     
}

public static MainActivity  getInstace()
{
     return ins;
}
public void updateTheTextView(final String t) {
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TextView textV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        textV1.setText(t);
    }
 });
}
}


 public class NotifAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          try {
            MainActivity  .getInstace().updateTheTextView("String");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

     }
 }
```